# Ellipsis : text is truncated but dots are not there

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Ellipsis is not showing the dots when text is clipped.

```css
.translation_wrap{
    width: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;        
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="tooltipparent translation_wrap" title="{{'NOT_IN_AUTO' | translate }}"><label>{{'NOT_IN_AUTO' | translate}}</label></p>
```

Result :

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: But it does work

Comment: with English text it work super fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/xywVN.jpg , try edit the code with your language sample text

Comment: Maybe there is some other element "on top" that hides the elipsis. Maybe it is another container that hides it's overflowing content.

Comment: @lupz I think you are right, I tried to use google translate and I tried to use a greek phrase in the `<label>` HTML element and it works fine with his language too https://i.stack.imgur.com/MevIh.jpg

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas tried with english , still doesn't works.

Comment: in the code snippet runs fine. I tried to help you, maybe add some `!important` and see if it work, if it work, then delete the `!important` and try to debug that selector using devtools.

Comment: The development tools of your browser are very handy to _inspect_ things like this. Right-Click the place where the ellipsis should be, select "inspect element" from the context menu and take a look around to see what is actually there.

Comment: Look if something overrides yoour property from the .translation-wrap class with the devtool of a browser cause the provided snipped works fine.